# How do I specify a particular branch other than master in my OpenShift deployment?

Tags: git, yaml, openshift

My objective is to build a container image from git, but only from a specific branch. In order to do that, in my `build.yaml`, I have to specify the uri of the git branch:

```
spec:
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: superset-custom-exporter:latest
  source:
    git:
      uri: https://gitlab.cee.domain.com/repo-org/repo-name.git
    type: Git
```

This will fetch the master branch, however, I want the `superset-custom-exporter` branch. How do I do that?

I tried testing the certain URLs[1] through web and through the command `git clone`, all of them failed.

1. adding branch name after `#`
2. using the exact web url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `ref` property to specify a branch name (or any other commit-ish):

```
source:
  git:
    uri: https://gitlab.cee.domain.com/repo-org/repo-name.git
    ref: superset-custom-exporter
  type: Git
```